# Nuget: Package Restore Failed

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I cannot update the nuget packages in my solution. I always get the error:

> "Package Restore Failed. Rolling back package changes."

Here is a screenshot of the packages:

[image]

Comment: have you tried 'dotnet restore' from the command line?

Comment: I've tried both 'dotnet restore' on console and 'Restore NuGet Packages' on the Solution but still does not resolve the update errors.

Comment: Sometimes a Visual Studio Restart is required. But if it still doesn't work you have to post the **error messages** from the Package manager console, its hard to help you w/o a clear description of the issue

Comment: Is there exist `global.json` in you project folder? Are you migrating you project from .net core 1.1 to .net core 2.0 ? I have the same issue with you when I migrating.

Comment: What`s your target framework? .NET Core 1.1 or .NET Core 2.0? If you want to update those packages, you should change your target framework to .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: just fixed this error by repairing the installation of aspnetcore 2.0 sdk in my machine. thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: @jengfad, glad to know that you have resolved this issue by yourself. You can convert you comment to the answer, and mark it, so it is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by repairing my current installation of netcore 2.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If there is anybody looking for alternative solutions you can follow my answer.

Recently I came across this problem when I cleared the NuGet caches in the project.

I was able to restore the packages only after moving the project files to a directory with a shorter length.

**Example:**
Initial project path (package restoration failed): 
`D:\Folder01\Folder02\Folder03\TheProjectFolder`

New file path (package restoration succeeded):
`D:\TheProjectFolder`

By changing so, you will be able to restore the NuGet packages, and having finished again you can move the project to the previous location.

This was the only solution that enabled the NuGet package manager restoration.
(Sometimes in the error console it will output different errors. But the root course for all the errors is the length of the folder path. It hinders the restoration of NuGet packages)